# Hypertrack destination location

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, hypertrack

Destination location is not visible while creating action in Hypertrack, While we are getting current location only.
Is there any approach to be followed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be set usecases for this and you need to be follow hypertrack official site. You create ride with the help of collectionid and set usecase ordered.

Comment: Thanks Anil, I did the same thing at it works perfectly @Anil Kumar